# Three threads take turns printing ABC

Tags: java, multithreading

```java
package ThreadLearning;

/**
 * @ClassName ABC
 * @Description TODO
 * @Author ABC
 * @Data 2021/12/10 10:25
 **/
 
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ABCEROOR {
    private static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static Condition A = lock.newCondition();
    private static Condition B = lock.newCondition();
    private static Condition C = lock.newCondition();

    private static int count = 0;
    private static Object object = new Object();
    static class ThreadA extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            synchronized (object){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    while (count%3!=0){
                        object.notifyAll();
                        try {
                            object.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("A");
                    count++;
                    object.notifyAll();
                    try {
                        object.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //object.notifyAll();
                }
            }
//            try {
//                lock.lock();
//                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                    while (count % 3 != 0) {//注意这里是不等于0，也就是说没轮到该线程执行，之前一直等待状态
////                        A.await(); //该线程A将会释放lock锁，构造成节点加入等待队列并进入等待状态
//                        object.wait();
//                    }
//                    System.out.print("A");
//                    count++;
////                    B.signal(); // A执行完唤醒B线程
//                    object.notifyAll();
//                }
//            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            } finally {
//                lock.unlock();
//            }
        }
    }

    static class ThreadB extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            synchronized (object){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    while (count%3!=1){
                        object.notifyAll();
                        try {
                            object.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("B");
                    count++;
                    object.notifyAll();
                    try {
                        object.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //object.notifyAll();
                }
            }
//            try {
//                lock.lock();
//                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                    while (count % 3 != 1)
//                        object.wait();
//                    //B.await();// B释放lock锁，当前面A线程执行后会通过B.signal()唤醒该线程
//                    System.out.print("B");
//                    count++;
//                    object.notifyAll();
//                    // C.signal();// B执行完唤醒C线程
//                }
//            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            } finally {
//                lock.unlock();
//            }
        }
    }

    static class ThreadC extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (object){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    while (count%3!=2){
                        object.notifyAll();
                        try {
                            object.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("C");
                    count++;
                    object.notifyAll();
                    try {
                        object.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
//            try {
//                lock.lock();
//                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                    while (count % 3 != 2)
//                        object.wait();
//                    //C.await();// C释放lock锁
//                    System.out.print("C");
//                    count++;
//                    object.notifyAll();
//                    // A.signal();// C执行完唤醒A线程
//                }
//            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            } finally {
//                lock.unlock();
//            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new ThreadA().start();
        new ThreadB().start();
        new ThreadC().start();
    }
}
```

Three threads take turns printing ABC. The problem I encountered is that after abca prints, only two threads are left to switch continuously, and the other thread does not respond.

Comment: This isn't a workable way to use wait/notify, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: Good glad it helped. It seemed like you were losing notifications due to race conditions.